# Migrating an ASP.Net-MVC Application to a New Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, migration, sql-server-express

So basically, I developed this ASP.Net MVC application on a Windows 7 box with Visual Studio 2008. It works well on the local machine, and I was able to host it in IIS no worries. I then decided to upload it onto subversion, and fetch it on a different Windows Server 2008 machine. I downloaded it, had the IIS document root point to my application folder, and started it up.

I can visit the site fine. However, as soon as it needs to do anything with the SQL database I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My ConnectionString to the SQL database is as follows:

```
    <add name="UserClaimsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UserClaims.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The error throws a wobble about allowing remote connections, but the database is local! Additionally, when I look at the StackTrace of the error, I see something odd at one portion:

```
OpenIdProviderMvc.Models.ClaimRepository.ResetAutoSend(String upi) in C:\OpenIdProviderMvc\Models\ClaimRepository.cs:40
```

The directory which it is referring to happens to be where I had it stored... on the development box! It is stored in a different location on the Windows 2008 server.

Where have I gone wrong in migrating this project?

**EDIT:**
Here is the full stack trace to provide a bit of additional information.

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846887
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject) +4860189
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +90
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +376
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +4861315
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) +44
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() +45
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() +20
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +57
>      System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +35
>      OpenIdProviderMvc.Models.ClaimRepository.ResetAutoSend(String upi) in C:\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.3.1.9337\OpenIdProviderMvc\Models\ClaimRepository.cs:40
>      OpenIdProviderMvc.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(String userName, String password, String returnUrl, Boolean resetAttributeRelease) in C:\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.3.1.9337\OpenIdProviderMvc\Controllers\AccountController.cs:66
>      lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +245
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7() +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +258
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__9() +20
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +193
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +382
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +123
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +23
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +144
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +54
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in the stack trace probably points to some path on your dev machine because that is what is in the .pdb files (have they been added to subversion?). I don't think this is related to the connection error and you will probably have to sort that out separately.

Comment: Yes the .pdb files are in on subversion, since I uploaded every file in the project. Could one of these also be telling it an incorrect path for my sql database file?

Comment: Nope, they won't do that. My guess is that either your connection string is wrong or the database does not allow connections for some reason. 
Are you sure the database instance is called SQLEXPRESS? Can you connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: You got it Rune! The machine I was connecting to didn't have a database instance called SQLEXPRESS. *phew*

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL Server 2008 Express on the server if it is not already installed.  ASP.NET needs sql server express installed to attach the mdf database file in your data directory.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/)